# Chartboost Reward Video Always Shows Up As "Earn 1 Coin." How Can I Change That? (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, chartboost

Ok so I recently integrated Chartboost ads into my app. I created a reward video button, but I want to change how it says "Earn 1 Coin" to "Earn 10 Coins." How can I do it?

Here's what code runs if the button is pressed:

```
  Chartboost.showRewardedVideo(CBLocationMainMenu)
```

Answer (score 1):

There's a dashboard option to change this, please refer to this link to their helpsite, it should tell you everything you need to know.

https://answers.chartboost.com/en-us/articles/201220275#custom-rewarded-video-behavior

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution :
 1. Go to your **Dashboard** of Chartboost 
 2. Select your current app 
 3. In App, go to **App Setting** drop down menu 
 4. Select **Rewarded Video** 
 5. Now You will get the option **Reward Per View** to change that value